# Assign result of SELECT * statement to variable SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, variables

I have a table with 700 rows. What I want to do is, to execute `select * from table_name' query on it and whatever result I will get want to store it in a variable and after that is done, want to traverse through each record for processing purpose? How do I achieve it? Any help??

Thanks in adv,
-saurabh

Comment: Looks like you could use a CURSOR. Then again, it's a good idea to see if you can deal with your data as a set rather than at record level.

Comment: What processing do you want to? Maybe it can be done without a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

you want something which is called `cursors`

> Cursors

You use a cursor to fetch rows returned by a query. You retrieve the rows into the cursor using a query and then fetch the rows one at a time from the cursor.

Steps

1. Declare variables to store the column values for a row.
2. Declare the cursor, which contains a query.
3. Open the cursor.
4. Fetch the rows from the cursor one at a time and store the column values in the variables declared in Step 1. You would then do something with those variables; such as display them on the screen, use them in a calculation, and so on.
5. Close the cursor.

hopefully this might help you [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: Try to include a summary of link contents here, so that your answer is useful even if the link is not available.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example I use to start with

```
USE pubs
GO

-- Declare the variables to store the values returned by FETCH.
DECLARE @au_lname varchar(40), @au_fname varchar(20)
DECLARE authors_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT au_lname, au_fname FROM authors
--WHERE au_lname LIKE 'B%'
ORDER BY au_lname, au_fname

OPEN authors_cursor

-- Perform the first fetch and store the values in variables.
-- Note: The variables are in the same order as the columns
-- in the SELECT statement. 

FETCH NEXT FROM authors_cursor
INTO @au_lname, @au_fname

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

-- Concatenate and display the current values in the variables.
PRINT  @au_fname

-- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
FETCH NEXT FROM authors_cursor
INTO @au_lname, @au_fname
END

CLOSE authors_cursor
DEALLOCATE authors_cursor
GO
```